# Laravel send same notification via different methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-notification, laravel-events

I'm trying to `->notify()` different users of the same type via different notification methods.
For example: I have `TicketCompleted` notification and its `via()` method contains: `return ['mail', 'database'];`. I also have both methods `toArray()` and `toMail()` implemented. So what I'm trying to do is the following:

Model `Client` that has role `Accountant` should be notified only via `toArray()` method;

Model `Client` that has role `Contact` should be notified only via `toEmail()` method;

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return different values in `via()`:

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
  if ($notifiable->role === 'Accountant') {
    return ['database'];
  } else if ($notifiable->role === 'Contact') {
    return ['mail'];
  }

  // default for all other clients
  return [];
}
```

If you use the same Notification for other models you also have to check the class of `$notifiable`.